# How to update component variable in service Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm leaning Angular and trying to create older projects in Angular.

One of this have a very simple subtitle function, where in onReady from YouTube API I used a setInterval to verify the progress of youtube video and check which text I'll show.
I created the service to YouTube and it's ok, my problem is: after I found the text how to return to component and show it in HTML without stop interval loop.

My best try was ReplaySubject, i create a variable and return with .next

```
broadcast: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject();
this.broadcast.next({ 'text': lyric });

Observable.interval(100).subscribe(x => {
    this.updateTime(); // function with .next()
});
```

In my component I used subscribe

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private api: ApiService, private ngZone: NgZone, private youtubeService: YoutubeService) {
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    this.video = params['name'];

    this.api.getVideo({ name: this.video }).then((sucesso) => {

      this.lyrics = sucesso['lyrics'];

      this.youtubeService.startPlayer(this.song, this.lyrics);

      this.youtubeService.broadcast.delay(0).subscribe((value) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.lyricShow = value.lyric;
          this.actual = value.actual;
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

With it I can update the variable in component and show but with a delay.
If I use this functions inside component = no delay but in service I have a little delay (interval + delay).

Return variable to component without delay, is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code from constructor to angular's `ngOnInit()` life cycle hook. And also you do not need to write your code within `ngZone.run()`.

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
        private api: ApiService, private ngZone: NgZone, 
        private youtubeService: YoutubeService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    this.video = params['name'];

    this.api.getVideo({ name: this.video }).then((sucesso) => {

      this.lyrics = sucesso['lyrics'];

      this.youtubeService.startPlayer(this.song, this.lyrics);

      this.youtubeService.broadcast.subscribe((value) => {
          this.lyricShow = value.lyric;
          this.actual = value.actual;
      });
    });
  });
}
```